# Background não aparece [HTML5]

Tags: html5

(Resolvido)
Não sei o quê eu fiz, só sei que agora ta funcionando :thinking:

Bom dia/tarde/noite.
Comecei a estudar Html5 essa semana, porém acabei ficando preso na hora de inserir uma imagem de fundo no projeto. Já tentei colocar o diretório inteiro da imagem, entretanto continua não dando certo...
Aqui vai uma parte do código em questão

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>Google glass foi uma bosta</title>
  <style>
    body {
 
 background-image: url("site-background.jpg");
 background-color: gray;
 color: black;
 }
    p {
     text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 50px;}
  
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Não sei se vai resolver, mas vc não precisa colocar aspas no nome da imagem dentro de background-image: url( site-background.jpg ); e confere se a extensão é .jpg ou .jpge vc tb pode tentar colocar uma altura no body, tipo height:100%

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Uso de CSS background-image e background-color](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/250385/uso-de-css-background-image-e-background-color)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tenta colocar ela no body. Faz esse teste. Se a imagem aparecer tem algo errado na tag style.

> img src="imagens/foto.png" alt="Imagem de página não encontrada"
>   width="330" height="202"

Comment: A imagem apareceu Igor. Deve ser algo errado na tag <style> como você disse, mas o que seria?

Comment: Eu não faço a mínima ideia do que eu fiz, mas agora ta funcionando...

Comment: Se está funcionando e você não fez nada por ser cache, cuidado. Limpe o cache e veja se ainda funciona.

Comment: Limpar o cache do navegador?